# PHP Streaming and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

What is the best way to display or deal with a large result on success while waiting for PHPto render that result.  I would like to use jQuery to submit a form, have PHP process it, and give output/feedback to users while they wait (either in a div or an iframe...in the example below I use an iframe).

I have the backbone of the xhr version that I found online, but I was wondering if there is a better way (I am aware that there is jquery mixed into this:

```
function submitForm(){
    $('#report_iframe').attr('src','/tests/stream_ajax/blank_iframe.php'); 
     $("#report_modal").modal({backdrop: "static"});

       count=1;
         xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhr.open("GET", "/folder/ajax_result.php", true);
         xhr.onprogress = function(e) {
           count = count +1;

         $( "#report_iframe" ).contents().find( "#content_loader" ).text('this is jquery count' + count);
         }
         xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
             //console.log("Complete = " + xhr.responseText);
            // alert("complete");

             document.getElementById("report_iframe").srcdoc=xhr.responseText;
           }
         }
         xhr.send();



};
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

J Doyle

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you are using JQuery. Why don't you use JQuery ajax ?

```
$.ajax({
         cache: false,
         async: true,
         type: "GET",
         url: '/folder/ajax_result.php',
beforeSend:function()
{
    count = count +1;
},
success:function(response)
{
    document.getElementById("report_iframe").srcdoc=response;
}
     });
```

Comment: This doesn't get me a load result output for the php stream like this does:

    `xhr.onprogress = function(e) {
           count = count +1;

         $( "#report_iframe" ).contents().find( "#content_loader" ).text('this is jquery count' + count);
         }`

What I'm looking for is some solution that can let the user have some idea of progress on the result.  

Also, in both cases (mine and yours) if I submit the form again, it does not perform the beforeSend (or seem to).

Comment: If you submit the form, it will surely call the beforeSend again. But it will be a new Instance.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Nandan, you should use JQuery Ajax, now for the part of the progress feedback you should add an EventListener for the xhr object and display it in your frame, it would be something like this:

```
$.ajax({

  xhr: function()
  {
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

    //Download progress
    xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var count = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        $("#content_loader").html('this is jquery count ' +  count*100);
      }
    }, false);
    return xhr;
  },
  type: 'GET',
  url: "/folder/ajax_result.php",
  data: {},
  success: function(data){
    //Do something
  }
});
```

For a better explanation and more information:
[Click here](http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/)

[Or here](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/56/how-to-get-the-progress-of-an-upload-or-download-with-jquery-ajax)

---

UPDATE:
You could also try something like this, it works well for download progress

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "/folder/ajax_result.php",
  data: {},
  xhrFields: {
    onprogress: function (e) {
     if (e.lengthComputable) {
       $("#content_loader").text("this is jquery count " + e.loaded / e.total * 100 + "%");
      }
    }
  },
  success: function(data){
    //Do something
  }
});
```

Comment: For some reason this is not working for me.  It submits and gets the final result, but I'm not getting any count result nor modification to the div.

Comment: Try my edited answer, are you trying to display upload or download progress?

Comment: Download.  PHP result.

Comment: What version of JQuery are you using?